# If $a$, $b$, $c$ form a geometric progression, then $\sqrt{a}$, $\sqrt{b}$, $\sqrt{c}$ also form a geometric progression.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to teach myself some A-level maths (in the UK) from a text book, but have come unstuck with the following question:

> If $a$, $b$, and $c$ are the first three terms of a geometric progression, then prove that $\sqrt{a}$, $\sqrt{b}$, and $\sqrt{c}$ form another geometric progression.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You'll find that questions here get a better response if you provide context (what are your attempts, where are you stuck?) than if you just say "here's my question, please solve it for me."

Comment: @platty Good point, will bear it in mind. Oh dear, -1 on my very first question. Not a good start, eh? Thanks for formatting my question btw (much nicer), I'm sure I'll get better with practice

Answer (score 0):

Since $a,b$ and $c$ are in geometric progession with step say $u$, we know that $b = au$ and $c = bu = au^2$. Taking square roots of everything gives $\sqrt{b} = \sqrt{a}\sqrt{u}$ and $\sqrt{c} = \sqrt{b}\sqrt{u} = \sqrt{a}(\sqrt{u})^2$ so $\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b}$ and $\sqrt{c}$ are in geometric progression with step $\sqrt{u}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I were to take an examination (although I'm just learning for it's own sake) would this be enough by way of proof? I guess I'm a bit uncertain as to what constitutes a mathematical proof... well, any sort of proof really but mathematical proof in this case